# How to write Clang plugin makefile with binary download LLVM and Clang?

Tags: c++, makefile, clang, llvm

I'am new to LLVM and Clang. I just followed this [tutorial](https://kevinaboos.wordpress.com/2013/07/29/clang-tutorial-part-iii-plugin-example/) and tried to build a Clang plugin on my PC. 
The tutorial's makefile is simple like this:

```
CLANG_LEVEL := ../..
LIBRARYNAME = PluginExample

SOURCES := PluginExample.cpp

LINK_LIBS_IN_SHARED = 0
SHARED_LIBRARY = 1

include $(CLANG_LEVEL)/Makefile
```

However, this tutorial's LLVM and Clang is built by compiling the source, while I get LLVM(and Clang) binary online directly(with apt-get install on Ubuntu). It's installed in /usr/lib. So, I'm confused where my CLANG_LEVEL is, what does it exactly mean?

=========================================================================
I have tried another way, but it seems to be wrong and I have no idea what did I miss. So, the makefile is like this:

```
CXX := g++
LLVM_DIR := /usr/lib/llvm-3.5
LLVMCONFIG := /usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/llvm-config
PLUGIN = ParameterNameChecker

CXXFLAGS += `${LLVM_DIR}/bin/llvm-config --cxxflags`
LDFLAGS += `${LLVM_DIR}/bin/llvm-config --ldflags`
LLVMLIBS = `${LLVM_DIR}/bin/llvm-config --libs`

SOURCES = PluginExample.cpp
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXES = $(OBJECTS:.o=)

CLANGLIBS = \
                -lclangTooling\
                -lclangFrontendTool\
                -lclangFrontend\
                -lclangDriver\
                -lclangSerialization\
                -lclangCodeGen\
                -lclangParse\
                -lclangSema\
                -lclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend\
                -lclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers\
                -lclangStaticAnalyzerCore\
                -lclangAnalysis\
                -lclangARCMigrate\
                -lclangRewriteFrontend\
                -lclangRewriteCore\
                -lclangEdit\
                -lclangAST\
                -lclangLex\
                -lclangBasic\
                $(shell $(LLVMCONFIG) --libs)\
                -lcurses

$(PLUGIN).so: $(PLUGIN).o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(PLUGIN).so $(PLUGIN).o

$(PLUGIN).o: $(PLUGIN).cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(PLUGIN).cpp -o $(PLUGIN).o

clean:
    -rm -fv $(PLUGIN).o $(PLUGIN).so
```

The compiler always complains sort of things like `undefined reference to 'clang::PluginASTAction::anchor()'`.

I'd like to provide more information if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you since I have built Clang on my Linux OS. [Getting Started: Building and Running Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html)